# ADAPRIME spoj tle

Tags: java, algorithm, math, permutation, primes

> [PROBLEM](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ADAPRIME/). This is a problem from SPOJ problems section.
>
> As you might already know, Ada the Ladybug is a farmer. She grows many vegetables and trees and she wants to distinguish between them. For this purpose she bought a funny signs, which contains a few digits. The digits on the sign could be arbitrarily permuted (yet not added/removed). Ada likes **prime numbers** so she want the signs to be prime (and obviously distinct). **Can you find the number of signs with prime number which could be obtained?**

**NOTE: Number can't have leading zero!**

**Input**
`The first line of input will contain 1 ≤ T ≤ 10000, the number of test-cases.`

`The next T lines will contain 1 ≤ D ≤ 9, the number of digits on sign, followed by D digits 0 ≤ di ≤ 9`

**Output**
`For each test-case, output the number of distinct primes which could be generated on given sign.`

**Example Input**
5
1 9
3 1 2 3
5 1 2 0 8 9
7 1 0 6 5 7 8 2
5 1 2 7 3 1

**Example Output**
0
0
11
283
15

**APPROACH**

> For each input, I am first finding all the primes upto 9999999999. For each test case, I first sort the array whose max size can be 9. After sorting, I iteratively find the next permutation, and check if its prime or not(which i have done already, so it takes a constant time now). But I am getting TLE. I have no idea where can i optimize my code.

**CODE**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main
{
    public static int maxSize = (int)Math.pow(10,9);
    public static boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[maxSize];
    public static int count = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //find all the primes till maxSize - 1
        preProcess();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while(t > 0)
        {
            String[] strArr = br.readLine().split(" ");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(strArr[0]);
            int[] arr = new int[n];
            for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[i + 1]);
            }
            count = 0;
            HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
            func(arr,0,n,set);
            System.out.println(count);
            t--;
         } 
         
    }
    public static void func(int[] arr,int pos,int n,HashSet<Integer> set)
    {
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        while(true)
        {
            //ignoring the leading zeroes cases.
            if(arr[0] != 0)
            {
                //parses the int array and produces the number.
                int val = parseInt(arr, n);
                //System.out.println("val = " + val);
                if(isPrime[val] == true && set.contains(val) == false)
                {
                    //System.out.println(val);
                    count++;
                    set.add(val);
                }
            }
            int i = n - 2;
            while(i >= 0 && arr[i] >= arr[i + 1])
            {
                i--;
            }
            if(i < 0)
                return;
            //finds the next greater number than arr[i]
            int index = findJustGreater(arr, i + 1, n - 1, arr[i]);
            swap(i,index,arr);
            reverse(arr, i + 1, n - 1);
            
        }
    }
    public static int findJustGreater(int[] arr,int l, int r,int key)
    {
        int low = l;
        int high = r;
        while(low < high)
        {
            if(high == low + 1)
            {
                if(arr[high] > key)
                    return high;
                else
                    return low;
            } 
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if(arr[mid] > key)
            {
                low = mid;
            }
            else
            {
                high = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        return low;
    }

    public static void reverse(int[] arr,int i,int j)
    {
        while(i < j)
        {
            swap(i, j, arr);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }


    public static void swap(int i,int j,int[] arr)
    {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }


    public static int parseInt(int[] arr,int n)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            sum  = sum * 10 + arr[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void preProcess()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < maxSize ; i++)
        {
            isPrime[i] = true;
        }
        for(int i = 4 ; i < maxSize ; i += 2)
            isPrime[i] = false;

        int o = (int)Math.sqrt(maxSize) + 1;
        for(int i = 2 ; i <= o ; i++)
        {
            if(isPrime[i] == true)
            {
                for(int j = i * i ; j < maxSize ; j += 2 * i )
                {
                    isPrime[j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**THANKS FOR HELPING**

Comment: Wouldn't the prime sieve alone (preProcess) take too much time?

Comment: @JamesKPolk. Yeah. recently I got to know that, the sieving i am using is relatively slower. I should probably use segmented sieve technique. I am going to work on that. and maybe tomorrow if i progress, will update here. Thanks

Comment: I also think the sieve is incorrect. You have to treat sieving by 2 as a special case because `j += 2 * i` is incorrect for i=2, it should just be `j += i` or `j += 2`. That should cut the time in half.

Comment: I'm not sure why you sorted the digits,  I would instead group all the even digits and fives together. Any number that ends in an even digit or a 5 is composite (except trivially 2 and 5). Your permutation enumerator should not even generate such values, they should be skipped entirely.

Comment: I tried this problem and I am also getting TLE not sure why. I can sieve all primes till 1e9 in less than 1s. Also checked with T=10000 and d = 9 on ideone and I am getting the result less than 3s. But when I submit my solution I am getting TLE. Even my Fast C++ solution is getting TLE so I think it will be really hard to get AC with Java.